# Add movie element error

Tags: javascript

```
class DOMHelper{
static addElement(title, image, rating){
    const destination = document.getElementById('movie-list');
    const element = document.createElement('li');
    element.className = 'movie-element'
    element.innerHTML = 
    
    ` 
    <div class = ".movie-element__image">
    <img src = "${image}" alt = "${title}">
    </div>
    <div class = ".movie-element__info">
    <h2>${title}</h2>
    <p>Rating: ${rating}/5 stars</p>
    </div>
    
    `
    
    destination.append(element)
}
static removeEventListener(element){
  const clonedElement = element.cloneNode(true);
  element.replaceWith(clonedElement);
  return clonedElement;
}
}
class ModalWindow{
    movies = [];
    constructor(){
    this.AddHandlerButton();
    this.CancelHandlerButton();
    }
```

Why when i press button add again and AddHandlerButton() is executed  it shows me an alert, even if inputs are correct and code adds more than one Movie?

```
AddHandlerButton() {
    const modalWindow = document.getElementById('add-modal');
    const addButton = modalWindow.querySelector('button:last-of-type');
    const cancelButton = modalWindow.querySelector('button:first-of-type');
     // DOMHelper.removeEventListener(addButton);
      addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let userInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
        let title = userInputs[0].value;
        let image = userInputs[1].value;
        let rating = userInputs[2].value;
  
        if (
          title.trim() === "" ||
          image.trim() === "" ||
          rating.trim() === "" ||
          +rating < 1 ||
          +rating > 5
        ) {
          alert('Please enter valid inputs (rating between 1 and 5)');
        } else {
          const newMovie = {
            title: title,
            image: image,
            rating: rating
          };
  
          DOMHelper.addElement(title,image, rating)
          this.movies.push(newMovie);
          this.clearUserInput();
          this.UpdateUI();
          cancelButton.click();
        }
      })
      
    }

   
    UpdateUI(){
        const section = document.getElementById('entry-text')
        if(this.movies.length == 0){
            section.style.display = 'block'
        }else{
            section.style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
    clearUserInput(){
        let userInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
        for(let userInput of userInputs){
            userInput.value = ''
        }
    }
    CancelHandlerButton(){
        const backdrop = document.getElementById('backdrop')
        const modalWindow = document.getElementById('add-modal')
        const cancelButton = modalWindow.querySelector('button:first-of-type')
        cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            modalWindow.classList.remove('visible');
            backdrop.classList.remove('visible');
            this.clearUserInput();
        })
        backdrop.addEventListener('click', () => {
            modalWindow.classList.remove('visible');
            backdrop.classList.remove('visible');
            this.clearUserInput();
        })
    }
}
class toggleMenu{
    constructor(){
        this.toggleModal()
    }
    toggleModal(){
    const button = document.querySelector('header button')
    const modalWindow = document.getElementById('add-modal')
    const backdrop = document.getElementById('backdrop')
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modalWindow.classList.toggle('visible');
        backdrop.classList.toggle('visible')
        new ModalWindow();
    })
   }
   
  
}
class App{
    static Init(){
    const toggleMenuInstance = new toggleMenu();
   
    }
}
App.Init()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык